# How do I change $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$ into $\cos(\theta)$ in an equation?

Tags: trigonometry

Just give me an example. 
eg. $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{1}{2}.$ 
I want to make $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$ become $\cos(\theta)$. Thanks.

[image: this is what I'm trying to solve. The question requires me to find out the value of cosθ.]

Comment: Well, cos(theta) = 2*cos^2(theta/2) - 1

Comment: Based on your picture, it would be easier to calculate $\theta$ using sine, since you are given the hypotenuse and opposite leg length. The equation you would want to solve is $\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{1.5}{6}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Just set $\theta = 0$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are saying: You first need to solve for $\theta$. After you know what $\theta$ is, you can plug it back into cosine. To solve for $\theta$, take $\arccos$ of both sides of your equation. This will leave you with $$\frac{\theta}{2}=\arccos \left (\frac{1}{2}\right )$$ Now multiply by two to get $\theta$ by itself, and you will have $$\theta=2\arccos \left (\frac{1}{2}\right)$$. Thus, the answer to your (example) is $$\cos(\theta) = \cos \left [2\arccos \left (\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]$$

Comment: I'm working on a geometric question and I find out something like cos(θ/2)=5.8/6 but it requires me to find out the value of cosθ.

Comment: Can you state the whole problem as it was given to you? I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\cos(\theta)&=\cos\left(\frac\theta2+\frac\theta2\right) \\
&=\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)-\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right) \tag{1}\\
&=\cos^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac\theta2\right) \\
&=\cos^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)-\left(1-\cos^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)\right) \tag{2}\\
&=2\cos^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)-1
\end{align}

Thus, we have the formula:
$$2\cos^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)-1=\cos(\theta)$$
which is how you would turn $\cos\left(\dfrac\theta2\right)$ into $\cos(\theta)$.

(1) is by the sum formula for cosine; (2) is by the Pythagorean identity.